# copy and pasting git folder from one machine to another?

Tags: git

Are the following steps viable or is there something dangerous that I'm not seeing?

- Create folder and initialize it as a git repository
- Make some commits
- "Manually" transfer folder to another machine via usb/email/etc.
- Make some commits
- "Manually" send it back.

I know it's not ideal. But I need to do some quick work on a machine that doesn't have access to my company's local git server.

Are there any perils I'm not paying attention to, or should this work smoothly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if it is upto commit (that is always relative to your local cloned git repository) then it should be ok.

But not recommended.

As an alternate solution you can also start a git server on your source computer and then also  do a clone on your target computer.

For Starting git server

```
   git daemon
```

For help with the above command, run `git help daemon`

After this just place a marker file in the .git folder of the repository of your source machine to grant permission to the git server to run the clone command on that repository. This is done by:

```
cd <root_location_of_your_repo>/.git
touch git-daemon-export-ok
```

Now, from your target machine, run the following commands:

```
git clone git://<ip address of your source computer>/<absolute_path_of_your_repo>
```

This way you can setup a git server on your source machine and you can perform all the operations git commit,pull,push etc from your target machine.

**Advantage :** You have no need to move your code again and again from source to target computer. You can work anytime and anywhere on your target machine without any hassle.

Comment: Answers my question and then some. I'll definitely give it a try!